# Change company label to Organization in Billing address

Tags: php, html, magento

I am new to **Magento**. I need to change a `label` in `magento admin panel` form.I have the following:

```
Magento admin panel>sales>Orders>Billing Address>Edit
```

In this path I have a `label` named `Comapany`.

My requirement is I need to change the label **Comapany** to **Organization**.
Refer the image for details:

[image]

I don't know where the form comes from. Please guide me where I should change. I need the file path. Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Just a change of the label in the backend or to show it as "Organization" on the frontend and emails too?

Comment: @Leonidas yes buddy I have changed the label in frontend. I need to change in backend, but I dont know in which file I should change. Please guide me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind changing "company" to "organization" everywhere in backend then you could use magento translate files.

For backend you can find it in: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/your_locale/translate.csv

Just open the csv file with some text editor and then find "company" in the translation file, in english case it should be `"company, "company"`, change it to `"company, "organization"` and all company words in the backend will change to organization.

Comment: I did as you suggested. But still it shows as company!! No change :(

Comment: remember to refresh translate cache in the System->Cache Management->Translations

Answer (score 4):

You no need to change in file or any csv just flowed these steps, your task will be done:-

go to admin>system>configuration

in your left hand side select Advanced > Developer

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now your problem has been solved, if it's vote for me....

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

For Any translation in backend you can go to: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/your_locale/translate.csv

add "company" in first column and  "organization" in second column than save that file

then flush all caches of magento. then check on backend

Comment: Tried buddy but not changed!!